# AWS CloudTrail without configuring trail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

I am new to AWS CloudTrail. I have gone through number of aws docs and unable to figure out how to read cloudtrails last 7 days logs through program without configuring trail or without getting charged.

I want to write a java program which will read audit logs from aws and process those logs. I know we can create trail and we can read logs from aws s3 bucket using program, but I don't know how to read logs using aws sdk api for last 7 days like how we get logs on aws console ( we can read last 7 days audit logs free of cost.).

We can get this done using - cloudtrail-processing-library, but the properties/conf file for this lib requires sqs url as argument which i don't have, rather I don't know.

Please assist me so that I can write java program.

Regards,
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lookupEvents API in cloudtrail for getting the list of events (any create/update/delete operations).
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudtrail/AWSCloudTrail.html#lookupEvents-com.amazonaws.services.cloudtrail.model.LookupEventsRequest

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am new to aws sdk can you give sample code to lookup events, that would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

The logs are stored in a S3 bucket and you can use AWS athena to process and query the logs if you want, so you don't have to write a Java program. If you do then that program will need IAM privileges to read from the S3 bucket that stores the logs.

[AWS Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail.html)

[How to find your Cloud trail logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-find-log-files.html)

[Java code examples on S3 bucket objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html)

[Java Cloudtrail SDK reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudtrail/AbstractAWSCloudTrail.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!  
I haven't configured/created cloud trail, so my logs are not stored in aws s3 bucket. Without configuring/creating cloud trail, we can read last 7 days management logs through console.  
I want to write java program to read 7 days logs without creating/configured trail.  
I have created IAM user and I have authentication key and secret for user which can read cloud trail logs. I think I need to write java program using AWSCloudTrailClient class.  
Just searching sample java code with this class - AWSCloudTrailClient.   Regards,  
Sachin